Identify a movie? "Bad guys get to do this!"
I remember only one scene from this movie, as I was just passing through my neighbors' house as a kid while it was on.  I think this was an early scene in the movie, and I think the kids in the scene go on to be the pro- and antagonists of the movie.
Two boys and a girl are talking, and one of the boys claims that he wants to be a bad guy.  When asked why, he responds, "Because bad guys get to do this!" as he dumps the other boy's ice cream cone on his head, "and this!" as he kisses the girl on the cheek.  Maybe a few other things.  He runs off, perhaps doing some sort of maniacal laughter, and the other boy kisses the girl on the cheek and says that "Good guys do this better than bad guys."
No idea anything else that happens in the movie but this has bothered me for like 15 years and I want to know what it is.  I think it was a western and I'm almost certain it was a comedy.

You're looking for the comedy Dudley Do-Right from 1999. From Wiki:

The story begins with three children and a horse. These are young versions of Dudley Do-Right (Dyllan Christopher), Nell Fenwick (Ashley Yarman), Snidely Whiplash (Jeremy Bergman), and Horse. The three talk of their aspirations; Dudley believes he is destined to be a Royal Canadian Mounted Police officer (Mountie) while Nell wishes to see the world. Snidely, however, wishes to be the "bad guy".

The scene progresses just as you described it. Here's the trailer:



